# Can you change a Site Template after it is created

Tags: sharepoint-online, publishing-site, site-template, cross-site-publishing

I've created a test Site Collection in SharePoint Online.  I used a Team Site Template.  In order to leverage Cross Site Publishing, the Site must use the Publishing Template.

Is there anyway to change this, or must I delete the Site Collection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the template, but a "publishing" is just a reference to a site feature, which can be turned on at will. [Here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/features-enabled-in-a-sharepoint-online-publishing-site-3ab3810c-3c2c-4361-9d0e-0cbe666ea0b0) is the support article that will walk you through the steps of activating the publishing infrastructure site collection feature. One you've done this, you can activate the publishing site feature. (site settings --> site features --> publishing)